# Read Photo from Contact - Android

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I've used this sample code:

```
public InputStream openDisplayPhoto(long contactId) {
     Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
     Uri displayPhotoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, Contacts.Photo.DISPLAY_PHOTO);
     try {
         AssetFileDescriptor fd =
             getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(displayPhotoUri, "r");
         return fd.createInputStream();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

I can't display this larger photo. How do i use it?